# What is the Euclidean Metric of the Right-Most Column of a Matrix called?

Tags: matrices, notation

If I have matrix like,

$$M_2=\begin{bmatrix} m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22} \end{bmatrix}$$

and I apply an operator such that,

$$r_e(M_2)=m_{12}^2+m_{22}^2$$

What is that called?

For a general $n$ by $n$ matrix $M_n$,

$$r_e(M_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n m_{kn}^2$$

Also is there any other ways to express $r_e$?

Comment: You could write it as $\|\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\cdot M_2\|^2$. I don't know if that's useful though. (It might be more useful in cases where $M_2$ is meant as a linear operator, and less useful in cases where it's meant as something else)

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing having a particular name and I can't imagine why it should!